# How to display days order for x-Axis in iReport using High Chart Bars

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm using *iReport Pro version 5.0.0* and I built a report using High Chart Line. The query output below is used for this chart. The first column *weekdayname* ordered in ascending order.

```
WeekdayName s_expression    volume
Monday          Open            1
Monday          Click           0
Tuesday         Click           33
Tuesday         Open            70
Thursday    Open            1
Thursday    Click           0
Friday          Open            1
Friday          Click           0
```

But in High Chart x-Axis order goes alphabetically as:
Friday   Monday   Saturday   Sunday   Thursday    Tuesday    Wednesday;

I've tried to disable order for categories in High Chart using `xAxis.Order.enabled = Boolean.FALSE` in order to use query output order, but it doesn't work...

Is any chance to make an order for categories (x-Axis) same as in query?? Or I have to convert day names into actual dates like 05/10/2013 and then order will be taken from chart??

Answer (score 1):

I had faced a similar issue before.
I used ORDER BY FIELD in my query(MYSQL) and it solved my problem. i.e, in your case

```
ORDER BY FIELD (WeekdayName,"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday")
```